# jqGrid: Get parent row id in custom validation function of subgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

Can any one suggest me how can I get parent row id in the custom validation function of sub grid?

This is a my code

```
 subGrid: true,
                subGridRowExpanded: function (subgrid_id, row_id)
                {

                    var subgrid_table_id;
                    subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_t";
                    var subgrid_pager_id = subgrid_id+"_p";
                    jQuery("#"+subgrid_id).html("<table id="+subgrid_table_id+"  class=scroll></table><div  id="+subgrid_pager_id+" ></div>");
                    jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid(
                    {
                        url:"form_subgrid_ajax_296.php?id="+row_id+"&child_form_id=296",
                        editurl:"../ajax/common_subgrid_edit_296.php?form_id="+sub_grid_id+"&parent_id="+row_id,
                        datatype: "json",

                        colNames: ['ID','PESO'],
                        colModel: [{name:'id',index:'id',editable:false,hidden:true},
                            {name:'peso',
                    index:'peso',
                    formoptions:{elmsuffix:''},editrules:{required:true,custom:true, custom_func:customNumberChk},editable:true,
                                hidden:false,
                                search:true,
                                editoptions: {size:80, maxlength: 1000}
                                }],
                        sortorder: "asc",
                        height: 300,
                        loadonce: false,
                        width: 500,
                        rowNum:10, 
                        rowList:[10,20,50],
                        sortname: 'id',
                        sortorder: "asc",
                        cellEdit: false,
                        cellsubmit: "clientarray",
                        caption:"Child",
                        pager: subgrid_pager_id
                    });
                    jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid
                    (
                    "navGrid",
                    "#"+subgrid_pager_id,
                    {
                        edit:true,
                        add:true,
                        del:true,
                        search:false
                    },
                    {
                        width:780,
                        recreateForm:true
                    },
                    {
                        width:780,
                        recreateForm:true
                    }
                  );
                }
```

Now look at the **name:'peso',index:'peso',** .I have used custom function customNumberChk.

This is my custom function

```
function customNumberChk(value,colname)
{

}
```

I want rowid in this function.

Comment: which kind of subgrid you use? [Subgrid as Grid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:subgrid_as_grid)?

Comment: yes, I am using Subgrid as Grid

Comment: in the case you have the rowid as parameter of `subGridRowExpanded` callback and I don't full understand your question. Probably the problem exist in the form hos you organized your code. You should include the code which you use currently.

Comment: I found that you included the code in your question just accidentally. Please write short comment to inform about the changes. It will produce notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important just the place where you define the function `customNumberChk` used for custom validation. JavaScript allows to access any variable defined in the outer scope. One name such functions as [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/111200/315935) for more information). So you can for example define `customNumberChk` inside of `subGridRowExpanded` anonymous callback function:

```
subGridRowExpanded: function (subgrid_id, row_id) {
    var subgrid_table_id;
    function customNumberChk (value, colname) {
        // one can use here ANY variable from the outer scope
        // inclusive subgrid_id, row_id, subgrid_table_id and so on
    }
    ...
    jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
        ...
        colModel: [...
            {name:'peso',
             ...
             editrules:{required:true,custom:true, custom_func: customNumberChk}
            }
        ...
    });
    ...
}
```

In the same way you can don't define `customNumberChk` function at all and use `custom_func` defined as anonymous function:

```
subGridRowExpanded: function (subgrid_id, row_id) {
    var subgrid_table_id;
    ...
    jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
        ...
        colModel: [...
            {
                name:'peso',
                ...
                editrules: {
                    required: true,
                    custom: true,
                    custom_func: function (value, colname) {
                        // one can use here ANY variable from the outer scope
                        // inclusive subgrid_id, row_id, subgrid_table_id
                        // and so on
                    }
                }
            }
        ...
    });
    ...
}
```